# Reading specific columns from Csv file for Matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

l have a csv file including 41 years dataset and csv file has 10 column which are date, year, month,day,pcp1,pcp2,pcp3,pcp4,pcp5,pcp6.l would like to plot these data by Matplotlib module but l have problem with getting data from Csv file.

here is example dataset of Csvfile:

```
date    day month   year    pcp1    pcp2    pcp3    pcp4    pcp5    pcp6
1.01.1979   1   1   1979    0.431   2.167   9.375   0.431   2.167   9.375
2.01.1979   2   1   1979    1.216   2.583   9.162   1.216   2.583   9.162
3.01.1979   3   1   1979    4.041   9.373   23.169  4.041   9.373   23.169
4.01.1979   4   1   1979    1.799   3.866   8.286   1.799   3.866   8.286
5.01.1979   5   1   1979    0.003   0.051   0.342   0.003   0.051   0.342
6.01.1979   6   1   1979    2.345   3.777   7.483   2.345   3.777   7.483
7.01.1979   7   1   1979    0.017   0.031   0.173   0.017   0.031   0.173
8.01.1979   8   1   1979    5.061   5.189   43.313  5.061   5.189   43.313
```

here is my code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



with open('output8b.csv', 'r') as csvfile:

    # get number of columns
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        array = line.split(',')
        first_item = array[0]

    num_columns = len(array)
    csvfile.seek(0)

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    included_col1 = [1]
    included_col6=[6]
    x=[]
    y=[]

    for row in reader:
            content = list(row[i] for i in included_col1)
            x.append(content)
    for row in reader:
            content2 = list(row[i] for i in included_col6)
            y.append(content2)


    plt.figure(1)  # the first figure
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

when l run code , l got empty "[]" columns of pcp.When l change `col1=[1]` to `[1,5,6,7]` ,l got this:`['2014', '0.003', '0', '0.003']`.how can l plot specific columns by Matplot?

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    included_col1 = [1,5,6,7]
    x=[]
    for row in reader:
            content = list(row[i] for i in included_col1)
            x.append(content)
    print (content)
```

Comment: I don't understand: your dataset file use **space** as fields separator, not "," or ";". What's wrong?

Comment: most likely an issue associated with delimiters.

Comment: l corrected my code but this time ,l m getting an error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,431' ".normally ,l checked typed of column and it was double.